# swift: add Haneke.framework to xcode 7.0.1 not work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, haneke

I'm beginner in xcode and swift, So I'm try to add `Haneke` framework to my project. I do these steps:

1. Drag `Haneke.xcodeproj` to your project in the Project Navigator.
2. Select your project and then your app target. Open the Build Phases panel.
3. Expand the Target Dependencies group, and add Haneke.framework.
4. Click on the + button at the top left of the panel and select New Copy Files  Phase. Set Destination to Frameworks, and add Haneke.framework.
5. `import Haneke` whenever you want to use `Haneke`.

But I get this error in `improt Haneke`:
**No such module 'Haneke'**

Also I'm tried to Clean and Build again but not work for me!
Is there a mistake from me?

Edit:
**More Info**
I used swift 2.0 and xcode 7.0.1 and development target is 8.0
Also I added some screenshots

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: I just followed those steps, and don't have the same error. Can you provide some more details? Perhaps you could share a screen shot of your build phases? What kind of file are you trying to import Haneke in?

Comment: @pbergson tnx for reply, I add more info for you

Comment: Strange. With the same setup, I don't get the error. The only difference I currently spot is that my Haneke.xcodeproj contains 4 groups (Haneke, HanekeTests, HanekeDemo, Products), which leads me to wonder whether there's some difference in the actual framework. Maybe you should re-download Haneke and try again?

Comment: which version do you used?

Comment: You are right, I downloaded again and HanekeTests added but problem exist yet!!! I'm confused

Comment: @pbergson No more idea?

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't have time to work on it. I don't suppose you can put the project on github so I can see your problem in action?

Comment: I solve this problem with build and compile as Haneke.framework file. Thank you body

Comment: Ok, glad you're sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found another solution, At first I opened Haneke project in xcode and create a build then Drag & Drop new compiled file (Haneke.framework) from build folder to my own project and it's working now for me.